# nested case - why must ";;" be put after possible commands and not directly behind "esac"?

Tags: shell-script

I would like an explanation about the termination `;;` in a nested case statement.

Is it documented somewhere ?

Why doesn't it work like this:

```
     #!/bin/ksh  
     ...    
     esac
     ;; 
     print "why here?"
     ...
```

but works like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

var1="C" 
var2=0

case ${var1} in
  A) print "A"  
  ;;

  B) print "B"
  ;;

  C) print "C"

     case $var2 in
       0)
         print "A B"
         ;;
       1)
         print "C"           
         ;;
     esac
     print "why here?"
     ;;  

  *) print ${var1}
  ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 4):

`;;` delimits the case blocks. So what the shell expects to find after it is either another *pattern* starting a new case block, or `esac` to mark the end of the `case` statement. `print something` is not `esac` and is not a valid *pattern*, so you get an error. If you want a *default*/*fall back* case block, use `*)` or `(*)`:

```
case $something in
  (foo) cmd1
        cmd2
        ;; # end of first block
  (bar) cmd3;; # end of second block
  (*)   cmd4 # default case block
esac # note that the ;; is not required before the esac.
```

Whether `case` statements are nested or not has no bearing at all on that.

Comment: One thing I learned from this answer is that the last block doesn't need `;;`. With nested `case` statements, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Seems well documented to me in Bash's man page:

*excerpt*

```
   case word in [ [(] pattern [ | pattern ] ... ) list ;; ] ... esac
        A case command first expands word, and tries to match it against 
        each pattern in turn, using the same matching rules as for 
        pathname expansion  (see Pathname Expansion below).  The word is 
        expanded using tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, 
        arithmetic substitution, command substitution, process substitution 
        and quote removal.  Each pattern examined is expanded  using  tilde  
        expansion,  parameter  and  variable  expansion,  arithmetic  
        substitution, command substitution, and process substitution.  If 
        the shell option nocasematch is enabled, the match is performed 
        without regard to the case of alphabetic characters.  When a match  
        is  found, the  corresponding list is executed.  

        If the ;; operator is used, no subsequent matches are attempted 
        after the first pattern match. Using ;& in place of ;; causes 
        execution to continue with the list associated with the next set of 
        patterns.  Using ;;& in place  of ;;  causes  the shell to test the 
        next pattern list in the statement, if any, and execute any 
        associated list on a successful match. The exit status is zero if no 
        pattern matches.  Otherwise, it is the exit status of the last 
        command executed in list.
```

This won't work because the `;;` notation is outside of the case ... esac block.

```
 esac
 ;; 
 print "why here?"
```

Also your example shows Korn shell (`ksh`), but the notation is the same from what I know about `ksh`. It's shown here as well:

- [Case (ksh) - Shell Programming and Scripting](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/12350-case-ksh.html)

#### References

- [The case statement - bash-hackers.org](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/case)

Comment: For clarification, the `;;` in a `case` statement in Bash is equivalent to `break` in a `switch` statement in C. Furthermore, `;&` (as made obvious by the excerpt) is equivalent to the `continue` statement.